# Cronjob every 9 hour

Tags: cron, cron-task

I want to run a script through linux cron which will run after `9 hour`.

For example: If current time is `00:34` and I start the cron now, then my shell script should run at `00:34` and then at `09:34` and at `18:34` and so on. For this I have entered the below cron :

```
34 */9 * * * /path/to/script/foo.sh
```

But this is not working as expected. So, Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to do that for every `9` hour window. The way you have currently scheduled it, it will run at `00:34, 09:34, 18:34` every day and not in `00:34, 09:34, 18:34, 3:34, 12:34` fashion.

You should instead run it every `3` hours (`24 hours/day`, `3` is the highest common factor between `24` and `9`), using an interim file for storing whether it is the first, second or third `3-hour` window of the 9 hours. Based on this value, run the task whenever its the first such window.